# How to use regex in C++?

Tags: regex, visual-c++

I have a string like below:

```
std::string myString = "This is string\r\nIKO\r\n. I don't exp\r\nO091\r\nect some characters.";
```

Now I want to get rid of the characters between `\r\n` including `\r\n`.
So the string must look like below:

```
std::string myString = "This is string. I don't expect some characters.";
```

I am not sure, how many `\r\n's` going to appear.
And I have no idea what characters are coming between `\r\n`.
How could I use `regex` in this string?

Comment: You have a big problem if there would be `\r\n` between `\r\n`. I would think you shouldn't have this kind of string to begin with. Anyways, what have you tried ?

Comment: @HamZa It's not going to happen.

Comment: How to differentiate between invalid strings `IKO` and `O091` and valid strings like `. I don't exp`?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd do a simple loop with `find`. I don't see how using regular expressions helps much with this task. Something along these lines:

```
string final;
size_t cur = 0;
for (;;) {
  size_t pos = myString.find("\r\n", cur);
  final.append(myString, cur, pos - cur);
  if (pos == string::npos) {
    break;
  }
  pos = myString.find("\r\n", pos + 2);
  if (pos == string::npos) {
    // Odd number of delimiters; handle as needed.
    break;
  }
  cur = pos + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are "greedy" by default in most regex libaries.

Just make your regex say "\r\n.*\r\n" and you should be fine.

EDIT

Then split your input using the given regex. That should yield two strings you can combine into the desired result.

Comment: You want the opposite effect using an ungreedy pattern. What you have now will match everything from the first occurence of `\r\n` to the last one.

Comment: ...and then you take that and hack and smash your input with that. :) I should have been clearer about this.

Comment: lolwut? Look at the difference of [greedy](http://regexr.com?35jfj) and [ungreedy](http://regexr.com?35jfm). Basically you got lucky since the `s` modifier isn't set, which means the dot won't match newlines